# In SAS, is there a way to sort using all variables except one?

Tags: sorting, sas

I've researched thoroughly, but it seems that there is no way to easily do it using either `PROC SQL` or `PROC SORT`.

At the moment, I have to list all the variables except the one I don't want, which is rather tedious as my table contains 50 variables. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you use dictionary.columns or dictionary.tables and use a macro get every column except the one you want?

Comment: Hi! That is an excellent idea; I didn't know that that existed. I'll try that out, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
proc sql;
    select name into :columns separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns 
where libname = 'LIB' and memname = 'TABLE' and name ne 'COLUMN_TO_BE_EXCLUDED';
quit;

proc sort
   data = lib.table;
    by &columns; 
run;
```